# (QTP/UFT) How do I use a test's input action parameters to parameterize a test?

Tags: quality-center, qtp

I am working with HP Unified Functional Testing 11.52.
In my example below, I'd like to use the test's input action parameters "C1" and "C2" in Action1.

Here is the code in action 1, it is just 1 line. I would like "C1" and "C2" to lead to controlling how I run the "Find" action.

```
RunAction "Find [SPFQuickFind]", oneIteration, Parameter.Item("C5"),Parameter.Item("C6")
```

I would appreciate any help in figuring out how I can get the C1 and C2 parameter to be used to parameterize my action. Thanks.

[image: My test]

Comment: Keyview -> Right mouse click -> Action Call Properties -> Parameter Values

Then changing the default things to be input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyview -> Right mouse click -> Action Call Properties -> Parameter Values Then changing the default things to be input parameters.